# Flutter Mapbox - Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. How to resolve?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, mapbox, mapbox-android

I was trying to create an app in flutter using Mapbox with their link to docs [Link](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#configure-credentials).

But getting error as the image shows:

Here is my app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.google_maps_for_rider"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.google_maps_for_rider"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.mapbox.maps:android:11.2.1")
}
```

My settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Mapbox Maven repository
        maven {
            url = uri("https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven")
            // Do not change the username below. It should always be "mapbox" (not your username).
            credentials.username = "mapbox"
            // Use the secret token stored in gradle.properties as the password
            credentials.password = providers.gradleProperty("mapbox_downloads_token").get()
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.1.2' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Mapbox Maven repository
        maven {
            url = uri("https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven")
            // Do not change the username below. It should always be "mapbox" (not your username).
            credentials.username = "mapbox"
            // Use the secret token stored in gradle.properties as the password
            credentials.password = providers.gradleProperty("mapbox_downloads_token").get()
            authentication { basic(BasicAuthentication) }
        }
    }
}


include ":app"
```

My android/buidl.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am a newbie here. Please help me and explain to me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix this ?

Would be glad for a one-to-one.